# Abstract class - hiding implementation in C++ practice

Tags: c++, oop

Recently I've been writing code similar to this:

messagehandler.h:

```
#include "message.h"
class MessageHandler {
public:
   virtual ~MessageHandler() {}
   virtual void HandleMessage(Message *msg) = 0:
};
```

persistmessagehandler.h:

```
MessageHandler *CreatePersistMessageHandler();
```

persistmessagehandler.cpp:

```
#include "messagehandler.h"
#include "persist.h"

class PersistMessageHandler : public MessageHandler {
private:
   PersistHandle ph;
   size_t count;
   InternalCheck();
public:
   PersistMessageHandler(int someParam);
   virtual ~PersistMessageHandler ();
   virtual void HandleMessage(Message *msg):
};
PersistMessageHandler::PersistMessageHandler(int someParam)
{
  ph.Initialize();
}
... rest of implementation.

MessageHandler *CreatePersistMessageHandler(int someParam)
{
  return new PersistMessageHandler(someParam);
}
```

The reasoning here is to hide the PersistMessageHandler. Clients don't need to include a header for the PersistMessageHandler class, with all the includes and types the implementation might need, and to more cleanly seperate the interface and implementation. 
. It'll always be dynamically allocated anyway,

All PersistMessageHandler users will just call CreatePersistMessageHandler(..); directly or indirectly get one from a factory.

But. I've not seen this approach used much elsewhere. Is the above good practice ? Are there other/better alternatives for simple cases ?

Comment: Why would anyone ever abbreviate "Message" to "Messge"? Is it a typo?

Comment: Great question!  I do this all the time and have always wondered if it was kosher.  Except my declaration is: `std::auto_ptr<MessageHandler> CreatePersistMessageHandler();`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825018/pimpl-idiom-vs-pure-virtual-class-interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always have to hide as much as possible. Your way (putting implementation classes into .cpp) is a common way to do this in c++.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good way to hide implementation details from your clients.  If you are working in Windows, you might also consider using an __interface instead of an abstract base class.

An Interface is an MSVC compiler extension that looks like an abstract base class, but has different rules for creation and destruction than a normal c++ class.  It's the standard way of working in Windows, so there are system supported facilities for working with out-of-process objects and for using them in .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - it looks like [a form of the factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Users of the factory aren't interested in its internal details, they only care about the things it creates.

Answer (score 1):

The process of hiding the implementation details is called [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_science)#Encapsulation).
The process of minimizing build dependencies for your users is called [Insulation](http://codingplayground.blogspot.com/2009/09/cinsulating-i.html). There is a great (but aging) book by John Lakos devoted to both topics:

[http://www.amazon.com/Large-Scale-Software-Design-John-Lakos/dp/0201633620](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620)

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing dependency on implementation details is indeed great, and hiding things beyond abstract base class (ABC, aka interface) is a good and idiomatic solution.

The downside of using ABC is that you lose value semantics of your class which could be or couldn't be acceptable/desirable.

One technique that also hide implementation details without this drawback is [Pimpl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom). Guess you should be aware.

I'll prefer ABC in most cases.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen typo, should be ABC (abstract base class). Thanks!