# C++ abstract or interface classes?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I found this question: [When to use abstract class or interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221512/when-to-use-abstract-class-or-interface]). But it was asked for `Java` and `C++` is different. There is multiple inheritence so maybe the answers are different too.

When shall I use an interface class ?

If I use the `PIMPL` idiom then there will be only one member which I only need to forward declare. And if I move the private functions into the `PIMPL` class then there will be only `public` and `protected` functions in a `abstract` class. So the difference between an `abstract` class like this and an ˙`interface` class is that in the `interface` class there shall be only pure virtual functions. Does it have any advantages over the previously mentioned one ?

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825018/pimpl-idiom-vs-pure-virtual-class-interface?rq=1) question.

Comment: Thanks. It is good, but I also wanted to know when to use abstract class (not with PIMPL) and when an interface ?

Comment: C++ has no concept of an "interface" type. The closest thing is an abstract base class.

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface class when the class hierarchy can be viewed as generic; child classes can be swapped without affecting the calling classes.

For example, there is an `std::istream` class.  Any function or method can treat input as generic if it requires an `std::istream`.  So, one can pass `cin` or an `ifstream` to the function.  The *interface* is consistent.

Use the PIMPL idiom when you want to hide the implementation from the interface.  Used in library classes.