# hiding implementation details by reducing number of populated headers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am developing a library. I have interface class that would be called from outside.

I have also an internal engine that should not be called from outside.

As I read here and there, I should hide the internal engine class and not even populate its header. Since I have the following structure:

**interface.hpp:**

```
#include "engine.hpp" 
class interface{
private:
    enigne eng;
};
```

**interface.cpp:**

```
#include "engine.hpp"
//code that uses member variables and functions from eninge
```

**engine.hpp:**

```
class engine{};
```

---

To solve the problem of populating "engine.hpp", I should change the code to:

**interface.hpp:**

```
class engine;
class interface{
private:
    some_smart_pointer<enigne> eng_ptr;
};
```

**interface.cpp:**

```
#include "engine.hpp"
//code that uses member variables and functions from eninge
```

**enigne.hpp:**

```
class engine{};
```

This solved the problem. However, from now `engine` is allocated dynamically. All its member variables are in the free store.

I can not understand that I have to change my design and allocate engine on the free store for solving the problem of hiding implementation details. Is there a better solution?

P.S. I am not asking about why this solution works. I know it's about knowing the size of engine class is mandatory if I would leave it on stack. My question is about asking for a different design that may solve the problem.

**EDIT:**

Both `interface` and `engine` have member variables.

Comment: Any solution offered will just complicate your implementation. If the cost of using the standard allocators worries you (meta-data wastefulness and/or speed), [you can always write your own allocator](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)

Comment: If `Interface` doesn't have member and just virtual functions, you may hide `Engine` completely.

Comment: There is always a hacky solution: use a single private `char data[<size of engine>]` and `static_cast<engine>(data)`. But that`s a maintenance nightmare and *really* hacky. Instead, writing your own allocator will probably be nearly as efficient, but much cleaner. Of course, first *measure* if PIMPL really is a performance bottleneck before doing premature optimisations.

Comment: There's a trade-off. If you value hiding the implementation more than you value making the implementation simple, then this is how to do it. If you value a simple implementation more than you value hiding the implementation then don't do this. Anyone who tells you that you must *always* hide the implementation is wrong.

Comment: @MartinNyolt The char buffer might be misaligned; you would have to ensure that it is properly aligned for the data members of engine.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the PIMPL idiom. The other way to hide implementation is to use interfaces, i.e. an abstract base class and a factory function:

**interface.hpp:**

```
class interface{
public:
    virtual ~interface(){}
    virtual void some_method() = 0;
};

// the factory function
static some_smart_pointer<interface> create();
```

**interface.cpp:**

```
#include "interface.hpp"
#include "engine.hpp"

class concrete : public interface{
public:
    virtual void some_method() override { /* do something with engine */ }
private:
    engine eng;
};

some_smart_pointer<interface> create(){ return new concrete; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "interface.hpp"

int main()
{
    auto interface = create();
    interface->some_method();

    return 0;
}
```

The drawback here is that you must allocate dynamically `interface` instead of `engine`.

More discussion about PIMPL and interfaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825018/pimpl-idiom-vs-pure-virtual-class-interface) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213259/whats-is-the-point-of-pimpl-pattern-while-we-can-use-interface-for-the-same-pur)

**EDIT:**

Based on STL containers and Howard Hinnant's [stack allocator](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html), a third way to avoid variables in the free store can be:

**interface.hpp:**

```
class interface{
public:
    interface();
    ~interface();

    // I disable copy here, but you can implement them
    interface(const interface&) = delete;
    interface& operator=(interface&) = delete;

private:
    engine* eng;
};
```

**interface.cpp:**

```
#include "interface.hpp"
#include "engine.hpp"
#include "short_alloc.h"

#include <map>

namespace
{
    std::map<
        interface*,
        engine,
        std::default_order<interface*>,
        // use a stack allocator of 200 bytes
        short_alloc<std::pair<interface*, engine>, 200>
    > engines;
}

interface::interface():
    eng(&engines[this])
        // operator[] implicitly creates an instance and returns a reference to it
        // the pointer gets the address
{
}

interface::~interface()
{
    // destroy the instance
    engines.erase(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. there is something I could not understand. In this case, is not engine is allocated on the free store also ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I edited my answer with an experimental version without dynamic allocation. I don't really know what to think about it, tell me your opinion

Comment: Umm, how is using `std::map` avoids the free store?

Comment: Oh my... I forgot about container allocation. My bad. I edited the code to use [stack allocation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)

Answer (score 3):

> I can not understand that I have to change my design and allocate engine on the free store for solving the problem of hiding implementation details.

You seem to already have explained it yourself:

> I know it's about knowing the size of engine class

Indeed. If the `interface` had a member of `engine` type, then it would necessarily need to know the size of that member - otherwise the size of `interface` itself couldn't be known. The size of an incomplete type can not be known. Defining the member type would solve that but conflicts with your desire to hide the implementation.

> Is there a better solution?

There is no *better* solution. PIMPL with free store - which is the pattern that you currently use - is as good as it gets.

Technically, PIMPL doesn't require you to use the free store. You can store the object anywhere you like. You could use static storage. But that would limit the number of instances that you can have. You can even allocate a buffer of memory as a member of `interface`, but you need to hard code the size of such buffer and it must match the size (and alignment) of `engine`.

I would categorise both of these theoretical suggestions as kludges - the latter in particular. Static storage may be worth it if your profiling suggests that the overhead of that particular extra allocation is significant and forgoing PIMPL is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard solution for this problem: It is named the PIMPL (pointer to implementation) idiom. And as the name says, it always involves a pointer (or smart pointer) to the implementation class because
C++ simply doesn't allow this:

```
class engine;
class interface{
private:
    enigne eng;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and completely ignores the OP's postscript.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, it doesn't. The OP asked for a standard design, and pimpl is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: If there was a better solution, PIMPL would probably no longer be the standard. It''s a negative answer, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @BЈовић, the OP didn't ask for the *standard* design, they specified they are aware of the standard design. They asked for a *different* design.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, he is looking for a better solution. The pimpl is also the answer

Comment: @BЈовић, the pimpl *is already* the solution he uses. And he specified he isn't looking to learn about its merits.

Comment: @BЈовић, duck-typing kinda says it is. Also because pimpls aren't obligated to always hide *all* of the implementation.

Comment: This code is not PIMPL. PIMPL would be `std::unique_ptr<engine> eng;` As it is, you're instantiating a forward-declared class. Edit: any pointer can be used, but `unique_ptr` is the most common.

Comment: Ah, I mis-read your preface that the code is intentionally invalid. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution to hide implementations *and* not force objects to be allocated on the heap is to put them in a `detail` namespace, and put the headers for those types in a detail subdirectory.

Note that some aspect of your implementation will be exposed as it will affect the ABI of your library. There's no solution that can give you *both* ABI insulation and avoiding allocating objects on the heap.

Chances are that you're best off using pimpl, as you describe.